# How can I extract hastags from textinput and safe in an array in React Native

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native

I want to extract hashtags from Textinput and save them in an array.

For example, the user enters

> "Hello world, #Good #morning"

I want to save the #Good and #morning in an array using useState.

So I will have a result like this

> hashtags = [#Good, #morning]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply loop through the string and in case you find a hastag(`#`) you can add the respective value(until the space is reached) to an array.

Or you can also use regex, like so:

```
const mystring = "Hello world, #Good #morning";
const hashtags = mystring.match(/#\w+/g) || [];
console.log(hashtags);
```